# node leads to homepage even without app.get('/',

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am new in coding, so sorry if my question is dump. I use passport.js with local strategy and encounter the problem to stay logged in when returning to homepage. So i try to add a req.user:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  if(req.user){
    console.log('user session is alive')
    .....
  }
  return res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});
```

but " user session is alive" is not showing at all. Continuing to experiment, i discover that even if i convert code to:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  if(req.user){
    console.log('user session is alive')
    .....
  }
  res.send('Hello world');
});
```

or comment the above code in:

```
/* app.get('/'....

});*/
```

node continues to display index.html as homepage. 
What am i missing; Isn't supposed that app.get('/'...) is the nessesary route to display homepage; How can i add a req.user request before leading to index.html; Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `app.use(express.static(...` somewhere in there?

Comment: Sounds like you have a `express.static` somewhere in your code. That is directly exposing the directory which contains your `index.html`.

Comment: yes i have, you are right...so i thought that node doesn't work as  apache server which search index.html by default

Answer (score 0):

Req.user will be only there, if you send a user object in your get request to the route of "/"

Your can send the user object from your frontend for example with axios.

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('/', {
  user: {
    ID: 12345
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Ok i agree with it. But how you explain the other;

Comment: The if statement doesn't evaluated, but the rest is, so res.send in this case.

Comment: `req.user` will be there if the request contains the cookie, and NOT the user object. Based on cookie, passport.js will load the user's object into `req.user`